# nonatomic, sigma-finite measure on polish spaces

Tags: measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

I'm trying to prove the following conjecture:

*Claim.* For every uncountable Polish space $(X, \tau)$, there exists a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{B}(\tau)$ (the Borel-sigma-algebra generated by $\tau$) that assigns positive measure to every non-empty open set.

I think this is true, but don't quite know how to prove it. In particular, I know that every Polish space contains a homeomorphic to a $G_\delta$ set of the Hilbert cube $[0,1]^\omega$. So one idea is to employ the homeomorphism. But there is no guarantee that the $G_\delta$ set has positive measure under e.g.~the product Lebesgue measure on the Hilbert cube. Another attempt is to try to utilize the Borel isomorphism between $(X, \mathcal{B}(\tau))$ and the unit interval. But it seems in that case one has to pick the isomorphism carefully to ensure that the open sets are mapped to open sets. I think that can be done but am fuzzy on the details. Any hint (including suggestion that the conjecture is wrong) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One way, maybe not the best, is to show there is a Borel isomorphism between $X$ and $[0,1]$.

Comment: @GEdgar yeah that's been my main strategy as well (to have $\mu=\lambda f^{-1}$ where $f$ is the Borel isomorphism). The only obstacle is to construct $f$ carefully to ensure that $\mu$ assigns positive probability to all open sets (at least I don't see it follow immediately from $f$ being a Borel isomorphism..but maybe I'm missing something

Comment: I think you need to rule out isolated points if you want full support and no atoms.

Comment: @Ruy ah goot point! actually the main thing I care about is that $\mu$ assigns positive measure to each open set (and could be a mixture of atomic and continuous measures for reasons that you pointed out). I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: In that case, the solution is to take $\sum_n 2^{-n}\delta_{x_n}$, where the $x_n$ form a dense set, and $\delta_{x_n}$ is the Dirac measure.

Comment: @Ruy right! brilliant! sorry I must be too hang up on the mistaken idea that a measure that assigns positive measure to every open set should be nonatomic. thanks so much! (on a side: I feel it's also true that if we rule out isolated points, i.e. focusing on the perfect subset of $X$, there is a nonatomic measure on that set assigning positive measure to every open set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that yields a non-atomic Borel measure of full support,  assuming that $X$ has no isolated points.

**Lemma**. Any uncountable Polish space has a non-atomic Borel probability measure.

*Proof*.  It is known that any uncountable Polish space is Borel-isomorphic to $[0,1]$, so it suffices to move
Lebesgue's measure over by such an isomorphism. QED

**Theorem**. Any Polish space $X$ without isolated points admits a non-atomic Borel probability measure of full support.

*Proof*.
Let $\{U_n\}_n$ be a countable basis for the topology of $X$.   Viewed as a subspace, each $U_n$ is also a Polish space.
Observe that $U_n$ cannot be countable or otherwise by Baire it must have isolated points which would also be isolated
points of $X$.  Therefore $U_n$ is uncountable and hence by the Lemma there is a non-atomic Borel probability measure
$\mu _n$ on $U_n$,  which we view as a measure on $X$ by setting $\mu _n(X\setminus U_n)=0$.

To conclude it is then enough to take
$$
  \mu  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty  2^{-n}\mu _n.
  $$